# Node.js puppeteer errors DeprecationWarning and UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I'm new to using node.js and puppeteer and i keep getting three errors and i can't seem to work out why i'm getting the errors or how i can fix them.

I'm trying to scrape the same website over and over again but sometimes end up getting the errors.

Error one:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of undefined
```

Error two:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
```

Error three:

```
DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

My code:

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const referers = require('./models/referers.json');
const agents = require('./models/agents.json');
const log = console.log;
const waitForDelay = (time) => {
  try {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(resolve, time);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    log('delay error', error);
  }
};

const runPuppeteer = async() => {
  let browser, page;

  try {
    log('started puppeteer');
    const randomAgent = agents[Math.floor(Math.random() * agents.length)];
    const randomReferer = referers[Math.floor(Math.random() * referers.length)];
    log('randomAgent', randomAgent, '\n randomReferer', randomReferer);
    
    browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: true,
      ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
      slowMo: 10,
      args: [
        "--no-sandbox",
        "--disable-setuid-sandbox"
        ]
    });
    
    page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setUserAgent(randomAgent);
    await page.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    await page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({ referer: randomReferer, 'Accept-Language': 'en' });
    await page.setViewport({ width: 1680, height: 1050 });
    await page.goto('https://SiteUrl.com', { waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded', timeout: 60000 });

    await page.waitForSelector('.mwButton', { visible: true, timeout: 60000 });
    const buttonElement = await page.$('.mwButton');

    if (await buttonElement.isIntersectingViewport()) {
      await page.click(".mwButton");
      log('button clicked');
      log(await page.title());
      await waitForDelay(10000);
      await page.screenshot({ path: 'screenshot.png' });
    } else {
      log('button not clicked');
    }
    
  } catch(error) {
    log(error.message);
  } finally {
    await browser.close();
    log('closing browser');
    await setTimeout(runPuppeteer, 10000);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are very common and generic errors node throws when you have an exception on an async function.

The problem in your code is the finally clause, it attempts to close the browser, but when your code fails to create a browser object, it remains undefined when it reaches finally.

You could do `if(browser) await browser.close()` to make sure it exists, if not there is no point in trying to close it...